# Allow to only purchase only one product @ Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

We're looking for a solution to hide the add to cart button if a product is already in cart. So that the user can not order more than 1 of each product.

A Mentor from `Codementor` wrote a function which hides the Add to Cart button if a selected variant is in the cart:

```
var updateCartButtons = function () {
    if (typeof (window.cartItems) === "undefined") {
        window.cartItems = [];
    }

    var cartItemVariantID, selectedVariantID, selectedVariantName;

    selectedVariantName = $('.swatch :radio:checked').val();

    selectedVariantID = $('#product-select option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === selectedVariantName;
    }).val();

    $('.buymarginsecond').removeClass('addedToCart');
    for (var i = 0, l = cartItems.length; i < l; i++) {
        cartItemVariantID = cartItems[i].variant_id;
        if (cartItemVariantID == selectedVariantID) {
            $('.buymarginsecond').addClass('addedToCart');
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

We'd like to change this function to the effect that the 
button disappears as soon as the main product is in the cart. 
So you can only order one of each product and not different variants of the product.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your product.liquid file where add to cart is button is show. It will loop through the titles in the cart and if found set the variable to yes. Then check if variable is no, not in cart and show add to cart.

```
{% assign in_cart = 'no' %}
{% for item in cart.items %}
{% if item.product.title == product.title %}
{% assign in_cart = 'yes' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if in_cart == 'no' %}
// SHow Add to Cart
{% endif %}
```